# CakePHP 3 run shell task on remote server

Tags: php, shell, cron, task, cakephp-3.x

My problem is:

How CakePHP 3 run shell task on remote server as cron job?

I have `crone-5min.php` and it's works every 5 minutes but I can not run `cake.php`...

`crone-5min.php`:

```
<?php
   system("wget http://nazwa_serwera.home.pl/public_html/cake/bin/cake.php > Hello");   
?>
```

How do I run it? Is it possible?

Comment: Are you getting some errors in logs ? Also another possibility of error, do you have wget installed on remote server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yessss!!!!

That is it!

`system('php56-cli /cake/bin/cake.php ScriptName MethodName');`

This command is running on remote server in file cron-5min.php and execute CakePHP tasks:)